# Create a numeric value from text

Tags: c#, string, integer, numerical-methods

I have searched allot on google without any results I am looking for

I would like to get a numeric value from any string in C#

Ex.

```
var myString = "Oompa Loompa";
var numericoutput = convertStringToNumericValue(myString);
```

output/value of `numericoutput` is something like `612734818`

so when I put in another string let say `"C4rd1ff InTernaT!onal is @ gr3at place#"`
the int output will be something like `73572753`.

The Values must stay constant, for example so if I enter the same text again of `"Oompa Loompa"` then I get `612734818` again.

I thought maybe in the way of using `Font Family` to get the char index of each character, but I don't know where to start with this.

The reason for this is so that I can use this number to generate an index out of a string with other data in it, and with the same input string, get that same index again to recall the final output string for validation.

Any help or point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not hash the string?  You can re-enter the same string, hash it again and compare the hashes.  Note that you might get different strings that have the same hash, depending on the algorithm you use, but it's already built-in to the framework.  Otherwise, you'll need to determine what values each character can have, unless you want to use the ASCII table.  Even there though you could have different strings generate the same output.

Comment: Thank you for your response, The ASCII table seems plausible because I need the final output in integer or so

Comment: In that case you can simply loop through the string and get the ASCII value of each character.

Comment: `var numericoutput = myString.Sum(x => x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `Tim` I ended up doing the following:

```
var InputString = "My Test String ~!@#$%^&*()_+{}:<>?|";
byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InputString);
int Multiplier = 1;
int sum = 0;
foreach (byte b in asciiBytes)
{
    sum += ((int)b) * Multiplier;
    Multiplier++;
}
```

Obviously this will not work for 1000's of characters, but it is good enough for short words or sentences

`int.MaxValue = 2 147 483 647`

Comment: I don't see how this is better than just calling `InputString.GetHashCode()`. Either it's not (in which case this is not a good answer), or you have not done a good job explaining the goal here.

Comment: @Pierre - Converting to `byte` is an extra step that isn't needed. See my answer for a couple of alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to converting the string to it's bytes, and if a hash won't meet the requirements, here are a couple of shorter ways to accomplish getting a numeric value for a string:

```
 string inputString = "My Test String ~!@#$%^&*()_+{}:<>?|"
 int multiplier = 0;
 int sum = 0;

 foreach (char c in inputString)
 {
   sum += ((int)c) * ++multiplier;
 }
```

The above code outputs 46026, as expected.  The only difference is it loops through the characters in the string and gets their ASCII value, and uses the prefix ++ operator (Note that `multiplier` is set to 0 in this case - which is also the default for `int`).

Taking a cue from Damith's comment above, you could do the same with LINQ.  Simply replace the `foreach` above with:

```
sum = inputString.Sum(c => c * ++multiplier);
```

Finally, if you think you'll need a number larger than `Int32.MaxValue`, you can use an `Int64` (`long`), like this:

```
string inputString = "My Test String ~!@#$%^&*()_+{}:<>?|"
int multiplier = 0;
long largeSum = 0;

foreach (char c in inputString)
{
    largeSum += ((int)c) * ++multiplier;
}
```